# Featured Image and Title get hidden on my Shopify Custom Website

Tags: shopify

I have custom shopify Website, when you go to blog level 2 page Featured image with title disappears. I have tried every single thing but can't able to get the solution.

Here is the SS:

I have checked all the css codes and Shopify Builder but can't get the solution

Comment: I doubt anyone could fix this without seeing anything.

Comment: Could you add the screenshot again, as it seem to be missing.
Also, do you get any errors, maybe liquid-errors?